# apply naive bayes on test data with nan-values

Tags: python, prediction, bayesian, naivebayes, weather

I trained an algorithm to make weather prediction on a test set.

```
'Naive Bayes'
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import seaborn as sns

weatherbayes = GaussianNB()
weatherbayes.fit(X_train, y_train)
predbayes = weatherbayes.predict(df_test)
```

The problem is, that my test set has nan-values, which I dont want to replace with 'mean' or something else. They should be ignored without removing them from the test set.

My train set looks like this:
[image]

My test set looks like this:
[image]

And I get the following error, if I dont remove the nan-values:

**ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore them, why would you not remove them from the training/test set? I mean, removing them will make you loose information, but do you need that information? Maybe you can take a look at some imputation methods explained [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-nan-values-62d50f738fc).
In case that you want to replace NaN with specific vlaue, you can use for instance:

```
df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)
```

This will replace the missing values with the arithmetic mean in the column.

Comment: The thing is that you can not always remove them or impute them. If I remove all columns where I have NaNs in my dataset I end up 0 columns. And imputed values do not make any sense when you do not have a specific property for a product (for example).